# How to click on a user & show the user details in another component/view with Vuejs router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-router

I am doing a project with Vuejs and I need to the following:

- Use an API & fetch a list of users (just the names of the users) in the home page.
- Create a custom search filter to find users by name.
- When clicking on a user's name, I need to redirect to another component & output that user's details in that component (only the details of the user that I clicked).

I have accomplished the first two tasks. However, I have no idea how doing the other third task. I was reading the documentation for vue-router, but I am not able to figure it out.

I used [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to fetch the list of users & [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users).

**User List Component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- List Rendering the response data stored in posts[] array -->
    <b-input id="inline-form-input-name" class="my-3 col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4" type="text" v-model="searchUsers" placeholder="Search Users..."
    ></b-input>
    <h2>Our users:</h2>
    <div v-for="user in filteredUsers" :key="user.id">
      <p v-b-tooltip.hover.right='"Click on user to know more"' class="users pr-2"><span>{{ user.id }}</span> - {{ user.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

// import axios
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'UsersList',
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
      searchUsers: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // custom search box for user names
    filteredUsers() {
      return this.users.filter(user => {
        return user.name.match(this.searchUsers)
      })
    }
  },
  // life cycle hook - calls axios
  created(){
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
      this.users = response.data
      // console.log an error if get() method is unsuccessful
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  },
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">

.users {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

The User list component's name is `UserList.vue`

I need to ouput the user detail in this component called `UsersDetails.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="user-details-wrapper">
        <h1>I am the user details component</h1>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name: 'UserDetails',
    data(){
        return {

        }
    },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

.user-details-wrapper {
    h1 {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

</style>
```

**Screenshot user list & custom search filter**

[image]
[image]

---

Any help will be truly appreciated it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

Add a route

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    // dynamic segments start with a colon
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User }
  ]
})
```

A dynamic segment is denoted by a colon `:` When a route is matched, the value of the dynamic segments will be exposed as `this.$route.params` in every component.

In the `Single User component` do an `AJAX` call in mounted

```
mounted() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + this.$route.params)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
}
```

Comment: You should really check the docs both for [Vue](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) and [Vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/)